# how get all records on database using mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried this:

```
  MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(...);
    con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM questions;";
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        int i = 0, len = reader.FieldCount;
        while (i < len)
        {
            Response.Write(reader.GetString(i));
            i++;
        }
```

returns only the first values from table. how get all?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `reader.Read()` until it returns `false`.

I've also taken the liberty of converting your inner loop to a `for` loop.

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(reader.GetString(i));
    }
}
```

Read this to read up on the `IDataReader` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx